# MySQL Group By Count with Zero

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT apdr.patient_id,
COUNT(apdr.patient_id)
AS x_ray_result 
FROM apdr
WHERE apdr.type_of_test IN ('x_ray_opinion_1', 'x_ray_opinion_2') 
AND apdr.interpretation LIKE 'kochs' 
GROUP BY apdr.patient_id
```

It returns the count for number of patients who have interpretation as 'kochs'. How can I modify this to get the count as 0 also with the corresponding patient_id in the output.

Any help is appreciated.

I get counts starting from 1, I need the query where I get 0 as counts also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT a1.patient_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM apdr a2 
    WHERE a2.interpretation LIKE 'kochs' 
    AND a1.patient_id=a2.patient_id) AS x_ray_result 
FROM apdr a1
WHERE a1.type_of_test IN ('x_ray_opinion_1', 'x_ray_opinion_2')
GROUP BY a1.patient_id
```

Edit: I've forgotten `WHERE` clause

Comment: Actually it works. Only you had minor spelling mistake and syntax errors. Please update with the following query.

Comment: SELECT a1.patient_id, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM apdr a2 
        WHERE a2.interpretation LIKE 'kochs' 
        AND a1.patient_id=a2.patient_id) AS x_ray_result 
    FROM apdr a1
    WHERE a1.type_of_test IN ('x_ray_opinion_1', 'x_ray_opinion_2')
    GROUP BY a1.patient_id


PS: The down vote is not from me. In-fact I upvoted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Someone has been down voting on answers in this thread.

Comment: Ok, I accepted your correction. We have to wait for bigger approval ;)
You're welcome ;)

Comment: @damienix, bigger approval granted ;) and +1, if not for being the correct answer, than for the undeserved downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than putting the condition in the where clause, you can use a case statement to return a conditional count. See:

```
SELECT apdr.patient_id, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN apdr.type_of_test IN ('x_ray_opinion_1', 'x_ray_opinion_2') 
                    AND apdr.interpretation LIKE 'kochs' 
               THEN adpr.patient_id 
          END CASE) AS x_ray_result 
FROM apdr
GROUP BY apdr.patient_id
```

Comment: Not me. I never down vote. Anyways the above query gives syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

> select distinct a.patient_id,if(b.x_ray_result is null,0,b.x_ray_result ) as x_ray_result from apdr a left join (SELECT patient_id,COUNT(patient_id) AS x_ray_result FROM apdr WHERE type_of_test IN ('x_ray_opinion_1', 'x_ray_opinion_2') AND interpretation LIKE 'kochs' GROUP BY patient_id ) b on a.patient_id=b.patient_id;