# MySQL JOIN with WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables -

```
tbl_business
------------------------
| id | name | lat |long|
|----|------|-----|----|
|  1 | aaaa |12.45|6.88|
|----|------|-----|----|
|  2 | bbbb |12.34|6.45|
|----|------|-----|----|
|  3 | cccc |12.12|6.50|
|----|------|-----|----|
```

and

```
tbl_deals
-------------------
| id | deal | bid |
|----|------|-----|
|  1 | xxxx |  1  |
|----|------|-----|
|  2 | yyyy |  1  |
|----|------|-----|
|  3 | zzzz |  2  |
|----|------|-----|
```

Now I want to find all the businesses that are within 1km of `12.44, 6.66`, along with the deals count. E.g.

```
| bid |dcount|
|-----|------|
|  1  |   2  |
|-----|------|
|  2  |   1  |
|-----|------|
|  3  |   0  |
|-----|------|
```

I'm using this query right now -

```
SELECT bid, COUNT( id ) as count
FROM  `tbl_deals` 
WHERE bid
IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM tbl_business
    WHERE ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 12.44 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( long ) - RADIANS( 6.66 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 12.44 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) ) ) < 1
    )
GROUP BY bid
ORDER BY count DESC
```

I found the formula [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch). But this doesn't show count = 0 for bid 3. I'm guessing I have to use Left join for this, but cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to write an outer join, a `business LEFT JOIN deals`:

```
SELECT 
      b.id
    , COUNT( d.bid ) AS dcount
FROM  
      tbl_business AS b
  LEFT JOIN
      tbl_deals AS d 
    ON 
      d.bid = b.id
WHERE 
      ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 12.44 ) ) 
                   * COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) 
                   * COS( RADIANS( long ) - RADIANS( 6.66 ) ) 
                   + SIN( RADIANS( 12.44 ) ) 
                   * SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) 
                   ) 
      ) < 1
GROUP BY 
      b.id
ORDER BY 
      dcount DESC
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I guess I should study a bit more on joins. :)
Any resource for beginners you might have? (except mysql documentation :P)

Comment: Also: [SQL Course](http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html) and [SQL Course 2](http://www.sqlcourse2.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, (select count(*) from tbl_deals,tbl_business a1 where tbl_deals.bid=a1.id and a1.id=a2.id and ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 12.44 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( `long` ) - RADIANS( 6.66 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 12.44 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) ) ) < 30) as count
from tbl_business a2
group by id
order by count desc
```

I use your data and change condition to satisfy the result.

reference:
[MySQL Group By Count with Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921178/mysql-group-by-count-with-zero)